# Prevent same site open twice - Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

This is a bit of an odd question.  However, I'm horribly sloppy with my tabs in firefox.  I'll open a bunch of tabs for different projects I'm working on and not come back and close them for days.  Sometimes I open multiple Gmails or multiple Outlook web access tabs... and more recently..  Grooveshark tabs.  Is there any good way of dealing with this?  I feel like it would be nice if I could define websites... that if I opened up a new tab and tried going to one of those sites that's open in another window/tab, it would bring me to the first instance of that tab instead.

Comment: Would the ability to "lock" a tab help you (a tab which can't be closed) ? I know I saw a plugin for that on mozilla's pages somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that isn't exactly what I was asking for in the question, but it does solve my issue..  Mozilla Prism lets you run a website in a separate window, like an application, with desktop and start menu shortcuts and everything. It is both a [Firefox plug-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6665) and [a stand alone product](http://prism.mozilla.com/).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do it exactly as you request. I'm unsure if we can reuse an existing tab when typing in an address if it happens to be on the same domain of an opened tab.

However, [Closy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1849) allows you to close duplicate tabs, while [TabCloser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9669) allows you to close tabs with the same domain name.

[image]

[image]